# can't simulate push notification on ios device

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apn

I was following along with a `raywenderlich.com` article on getting started with push notifications because I wanted to try it out on my app, and was able to easily follow along up until the part where you run the command in the terminal and actually simulate the notification.

When I run the command `xcrun simctl push 'device identifier here' site.bundleidentifier.example eventnotification.apn`, I get an error saying `Invalid device: 'device identifier here'`. I can't seem to figure out the issue, I got the identifier straight from Xcode. I went to Window -> Devices & Simulators -> Devices and grabbed the identifier of my phone. I can't seem to figure out how to resolve the error, if anybody knows how I can fix this, that would be great, thanks.

Link to the article: [Push Notification Article Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/11395893-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started)

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you may be trying to do this with your actual phone. This command refers to pushing to the simulator (`simctl` is the command line app that controls the simulator).

You can list the available devices by doing the following terminal command:

```
xcrun simctl list 'devices' 'booted'
```

A great trick is just using `booted` to use the open simulator. So, a sample command might be:

```
xcrun simctl push booted com.myprogram.app payload.json
```

Or, if you want to use the full device ID:

```
xcrun simctl push 'xxxxxxx-7C2B-4B0D-A0E2-xxxxxxxxx' com.myprogram.app payload.json
```

Where you replace the info in the single quotes with your device ID.

Comment: Oh okay I see, is there any command that can be used for an actual ios device instead of the ios simulator? I tried it on the simulator right after and it worked great. @jnpdx

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: my fault, I kept reading down and seen a section of pushing notifications to a real device, has nothing to do with this issue. @jnpdx

Comment: Yeah, the device is a different beast. If this answer still cleared some things up, or helped, please consider upvoting it.